# How to setup a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells

I'm dealing with this situation, I created a tableView with reusable cells, I setup that cell with shadow, everything is ok but when I tap a cell twice the cell the cell is painted again, I don't want this what I want is the cell shown in the view at the beginning the first screen is the first view, the second one is the view when I tapped a cell, I want, no matter if I tap a cell, I don't want That the shadow increase, that I want is that cell stays as it is at the beginning.

Here's my code and my views. Thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.sodas[indexPath.row]


    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 20)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6

    cell.clipsToBounds = false

    let shadowFrame: CGRect = (cell.layer.bounds)
    let shadowPath: CGPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowFrame).cgPath
    cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath

    return cell
}
```

[image: first view]

[image: second view]

Answer (score 3):

A cell's frame isn't set in `cellForRowAt`. It's too soon. You should use the `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` delegate method to setup the cell's shadow frame.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.sodas[indexPath.row]

    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 20)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6

    cell.clipsToBounds = false

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let shadowFrame: CGRect = (cell.layer.bounds)
    let shadowPath: CGPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowFrame).cgPath
    cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath
}
```